# I have used jQuery datatable plugin to display backend data it is working but page number in pagination is not displaying.Following is code segment

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Following is code segment.

```
$("#my_table").DataTable({
  "scrollY":300+"px",
  "searching":false,
  "bInfo":false,
  "scrollCollapse":false,
  "bLengthChange":false,
  "pageLength":5,
  "processing":true,
  "serverSide":true,
  "paging":true,
  "ajax":{
    url:'fetch_transaction.php',
    type:'get',
    data:account_query,
    dataSrc:function(json)
    {
      account_query.last_balance=json.account_data.last_balance;
      account_query.balance_type=json.account_data.balance_type;
      return json.data;
    }
  },
  "ordering":false,
  "destroy":true,
});
```

Comment: Does your JSON response (from PHP to the web page) contain the relevant data to allow DataTables to show this information correctly? See `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` as described [in this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). The same page also has [example data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data).

Comment: Thank you it worked.recordsTotal  had been set to 0

Comment: is there any way to update parameter to be sent to serverside on clicking page number in pagination? In above case i want some way to update  'data:account_query'  when user click on page number

Comment: You can use a function, so the variable is re-populated for each call: `data: function ( d ) { d.account_query = account_query; }`. You can see more details [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data). Bear in mind that this data is sent to the server _before_ you receive any data in the `dataSrc` response - so it will be empty to begin with.